Image freezing with OpenCv
I'm trying to make a game be automated, but when i run my code the image i get in the preview is the same image i got when i started the game. It's like the first image from the game is being saved and now every time i run the code the saved image shows up.
I think the problem is the image is being saved and every time i close and open the game i'm trying to automate, the image resets.
Thats my code:
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con
import time

class Vision:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hwnd = None

        def WindowCapture():
            cv.startWindowThread()
            self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, '3Kings')
            self.wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
            self.dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(self.wDC)
            self.cDC = self.dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
            self.dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
            self.dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(self.dcObj, 1920, 1080)
            self.cDC.SelectObject(self.dataBitMap)
            self.cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (1920, 1080), self.dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

            # Save the screenshot
            self.signedIntsArray = self.dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
            self.img = np.frombuffer(self.signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
            self.img.shape = (1080, 1920, 4)

            # Free Resources
            self.dcObj.DeleteDC()
            self.cDC.DeleteDC()
            win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, self.wDC)
            win32gui.DeleteObject(self.dataBitMap.GetHandle())
            
            self.img = self.img[..., :3]
            self.img = np.ascontiguousarray(self.img)
            
            return self.img
        
        while True:
            cv.imshow('Preview', WindowCapture())
            
            if cv.waitKey(100) == ord('q'):
                break
        cv.destroyAllWindows()

Vision()

